# Base interceptor in redux observable and ajax

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have a question regarding redux observable and ajax request.

I have been using redux observable since I started learning to react.

So I actually wanted to ask is there any way to intercept all ajax request to set baseurl n headers??

Let me tell you how I do this in ajax. I simply make 4 base functions of **ajaxGet**,**ajaxPost**,**ajaxDel**, and **ajaxPut**. and use those functions to call the APIs everywhere in the application.

In those base functions, I set the baseurl and default headers.

Let me know if anybody found some better approach like base interceptor or something else other than making base functions.

One more question is that how most of you write a refresh token mechanism in the application while using redux observable and rxjs.

I have followed this tutorial in many of my applications.

> https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-get-a-new-access-token-using-redux-observables-and-the-refresh-token-api-d38d875a8add

Comment: How about using axios?

Comment: yea @RohanAgarwal we can use axios but when we are using rxjs i think one should prefer using rxjs ajax operator because it gives you more flexibility. 

The problem with axios is that for every request i have to convert axios request to an observable and this goes messy :(

Comment: @HafizMuhammadShoaib, the RxJS ajax helper is not very robust and it should not be preferred. It is fairly trivial to convert from promises to observables, and many RxJS operators do it automatically. Ex1: `from(axios.get(url))`. Ex2: `of(url1, url2, url3).pipe(flatMap(axios.get))`.

Answer (score 0):

**INTERCEPTOR PROPOSAL WITH AJAX RXJS**

- Officially there is no way in the rxjs documentation to intercept your AJAX.
- Personally I prefer to use observables than promises, they seem much more powerful to me.
- I share with you an interceptor that I built using the tools available in rxjs. It also includes Bearer token authentication.

*Interceptor*

```
import { AjaxConfig, ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { catchError, throwError, retry, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import authenticateService from './authenticate.service';

const ajaxIntercept = (req: AjaxConfig) => {
  req.headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
  };
  return ajax(req).pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        return authenticateService.observableDataToken().pipe(
          switchMap(r => {
            const token = r.response.data.token;
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            req.headers = {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            };
            return throwError(() => req);
          }),
        );
      } else {
        return throwError(() => req);
      }
    }),
    retry(2),
  );
};

export default ajaxIntercept;
```

*Using the interceptor*

```
import { AjaxResponse } from 'rxjs/ajax';

const requestFunction = (id: string, body:modelbody) => {
ajaxIntercept({
  url: `${API}example/${id}`,
  method: 'POST',
  body: body,
}).subscribe({
  next: r => {
    const data = r as AjaxResponse<youModel>;
  },
  error: e => {
    /** */
  },
});
```

};

*Important considerations*

- retry we can configure the number of times we want to launch the request when X error occurs. For this example, set cos 1 when you make the request and the token expires. 2 renew the token and launch the request.
- req.url you can configure the base url within the interceptor if you wish. For the example, send the url when I call the interceptor function, it may be that you need to work with different urls
- catchError-pipe-switchMap inside the error, as I can validate the type and execute the actions I want in the example provided, I use the pipes and switchmap to make a token renewal request before relaunching the pending request.
- for the example work with Hooks. in Nextjs
- When I call the interceptor function it configures the desired request 'POST' 'PUT' 'GET' .... etc